# Height is not responsive Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay-theme

I have a problem when moving to dispostivos both tablet and mobile, boxes I move differently. Could not they be small at once?

In the following image it looks like are different. They are not 100% responsive because they do not go together or increasing or decreasing screen.

-->>>> CODE EXAMPLE: http://www.bootply.com/2oNSFtdw9Z  <<<<---

The first image is tablet mode and the second mode mobile

[image: modeTablet]

[image: modeMobile]

Regards!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the link you provided seems to be working perfectly fine but just in case, you can try to set the image height to be 100% of the div it's contained in.

```
.imagenContenido img {
height: 100%;
}
```

This will cause the image to stretch vertically to fill the entire div. Just be careful not to set a fixed width on the div or image or else your image will distort.